# How to add unescaped stringified JSON in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to send a `postMessage` using JavaScript in an EJS template, and I need to send a simple stringified JSON object that looks like this:

```json
{ "id": "1234567890" }
```

When I try to pass this object in an EJS template, the double-quotes (`"`) get escaped into `&#34;`. Here's my template:

```js
<script>
    if (window.opener) {
        window.opener.postMessage('<%= JSON.stringify(user) %>', "http://localhost:3000")
        window.close()
    }
</script>
```

The stringified object gets turned into this:

```
&#34;{&#34;id&#34;:&#34;1234567890&#34;}&#34;
```

What can I do to prevent the special characters from being escaped by EJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I need to replace `<%=` with `<%-` to use unescaped characters.

So my code would have to be:

```js
<script>
    if (window.opener) {
        window.opener.postMessage('<%- JSON.stringify(user) %>', "http://localhost:3000")
        window.close()
    }
</script>
```

Source: https://github.com/tj/ejs/tree/1.0.0#features